# After screen Reattaching, previous bash broken

Tags: terminal, gnu-screen

After I reattach screen session :

```
screen -DR already_attached_session
```

My previous terminal is broken with broken bash:

```
[remote power detached]

Warning: Program '/bin/bash' crashed.
```

I can not recover it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

Any idea what goes wrong  and how can I avoid it ? (reattach properly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the lowercase `-d` option instead of `-D`. The `-D` option is forceful.